# Помогите разобраться с BASH-скриптом

Tags: bash

Нужен скрипт, отправляющий юзеру из 3-го параметра содержимое файла, задаваемое 2-ым параметром. С частотой задаваемой 1-ым параметром, пока юзер не введёт "quit". Я совсем новенький, не понимаю в чём ошибка:

```
#!/bin/bash

while [ $exit -ne "quit" ]
do

read $exit
cat $2 | write $3
sleep $1

done
```

error: exit: numeric argument required
???
Почему? Я же строку хочу ввести и сравнить с другой строкой "quit". Что я делаю не так?

Comment: while в фон отправь, а рид вынеси за цикл

Comment: Что значит отправить while в фон? я только знаю, что & запускает процесс вне терминала.

Comment: & не открепляет процесс от терминала

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash
```

Нужны отдельные циклы, чтоб read не блокировал отправку

```
(while true
do
  cat $2 | write $3
  sleep $1
done
) 2>/dev/null &
```

Уводим отправку в фон и сохраним pid

```
sendpid=$!
```

У ТС несколько ошибок с условием выхода были. Так правильно

```
while [[ "$cmd" != "quit" ]]
do
  read -p "cmd:" cmd
done
```

Ну и прибить фоновый процесс перед выходом обязательно

```
kill $sendpid
exit 0
```